# bootstrap 4 list items that have d-flex class do not respond to .hide()?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I add class `d-flex` my Bootstrap 4 `<ul>` list items do not respond to `.hide()` anymore, even though `style="display: none;"` is added to the DOM.

The `d-flex` is used for the [Bootstrap 4 list badges](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#with-badges).

Suggestions?

```js
// test 1: regular list, no issue
$("#myList li:even").addClass("disabled").hide()
// <li class="list-group-item" style="display: none;">First item</li>


// test 2: list with badges, no response to hide (class "disabled" still works)
// just adding class "d-flex" is sufficient to reproduce issue
//$("#myList2 li").addClass("d-flex")

$("#myList2 li").addClass("d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center")
$("#myList2 li").append("<span class='badge badge-primary'>test</span>")

$("#myList2 li:even").addClass("disabled").hide()

// <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="display: none;">First item<span class="badge badge-primary">test</span></li>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h3>regular list</h3>
<ul class="list-group" id="myList">
 <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Fourth item</li>
</ul>


<h3>with d-flex class (used for badge)</h3>
<ul class="list-group" id="myList2">
 <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Fourth item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`.d-flex` uses `!important` which overrides the `display: none` which `hide()` puts on the element.

You could put containers within your li (I've used divs in example fiddle) and add `.d-flex` onto them so `display: none` on the li won't be overridden.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ks5nf9be/2/)

Comment: Such a joke to use !important... they even rejected a PR https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22076

Answer (score 16):

it doesn't work beacause `.d-flex` uses `!important`, which overrides the display: none which is added on the target element by the `hide()` function'.

Since you intend to hide the element, I don't think removing the d-flex class will be a problem.

```
$('.hide').click(function(){
  $(".my-flex").removeClass("d-flex").addClass("d-none");
});
```

So when you intend to show the element again you can use

```
$('.show').click(function(){
  $(".my-flex").addClass("d-flex").removeClass("d-none");
});
```

Alternatively, you can add a parent element which you can then hide and show at any time

Answer (score 7):

How I resolved was to **not** use `class="d-flex"` and instead use `style="display:flex;"`.

This negates the `!important` from Bootstrap's `d-flex` class. The result is `display:none;` will work when using the JQuery `hide()` function. When using JQuery `show()` function, the `display:flex;` is re-added.

Answer (score 6):

`.hide()` sets display to block, and you are using flex,  use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` to `show` `hide` the flex container.

**EDIT:**

Apart from all you are using the scripts outside document ready or in the code snippet you added them outside the `$(document).ready()` function and you are using `jquery.slim` so features would be minimal and add `display:none` to your lis which will be the real thing

**EDIT2**

this could be done in 2 ways one is including a class and adding `display:none` property, OR the second one which I prefer too, is to call `.hide()` before you call the `.toggleClass()` which means the `onclick` event will be converted to

```
$("#hide").on('click', function() {
    $("#myList2 li:even").hide().toggleClass('d-flex');
  });
```

Now you can remove the class `#myList2 li` from the `CSS` that i used in the demo.

See the demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // test 1: regular list, no issue
  $("#myList li:even").addClass("disabled").hide()
  // <li class="list-group-item" style="display: none;">First item</li>


  // test 2: list with badges, no response to hide (class "disabled" still works)
  // just adding class "d-flex" is sufficient to reproduce issue
  //$("#myList2 li").addClass("d-flex")

  $("#myList2 li").addClass("d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center")
  $("#myList2 li").append("<span class='badge badge-primary'>test</span>")
  $("#myList2 li:even").addClass("disabled");


  // <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="display: none;">First item<span class="badge badge-primary">test</span></li>
  $("#hide").on('click', function() {
    $("#myList2 li:even").toggleClass('d-flex');
  });
});
```

```css
#myList2 li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h3>regular list</h3>
<ul class="list-group" id="myList">
  <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Fourth item</li>
</ul>

<button id="hide">HIDE /SHOW NOW</button>
<h3>with d-flex class (used for badge)</h3>
<ul class="list-group" id="myList2">
  <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Fourth item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you are welcome @wivku and i just updated and added some more info please revise

Answer (score 4):

As already explained by previous answer, bootstrap's `d-flex` class is defined as `display: flex !important;`

In my case (active tab panes still showing div's from inactive panes if those divs are marked `d-flex`), I solved it with a custom rule:

```css
div.tab-pane:not(.show).d-flex,
div.tab-pane:not(.show) .d-flex {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: exactly - the most specific solution when nav-tabs are involved. I owe you a beer

Answer (score 3):

in general terms I agree with the solution by @Matthew Allen, but, in case you already have your project working and don't want to rework all your HTMLs, consider using a single CSS rule like this:

```
.d-flex[style*="display:none"], .d-flex[style*="display: none"] {
    display:none !important;
}
```

To my understanding, Bootstrap CSS code adds 'display:flex !important' in order to make d-flex prevalent to other display classes, but I don't think it has to override inlined display:none.